# Finding the steady-state $c$ for the function $y = Ae^{-\alpha t} + Be^{-\beta t} + C$

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

I have a decaying signal wherby I want to calculate the final steady state C as early as possible.

$$y = Ae^{-\alpha t} + Be^{-\beta t} + C$$

I am able to obtain measurements of $y$ and therefore form simultaneous equations.

Let $u = e^{-\alpha}$ and let $v = e^{-\beta}$

Obtain 5 evenly spaced samples of $y$ at times $t = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4$

$$y_1 = Au^0 + Bv^0 + C = A + B + C$$
$$y_2 = Au^1 + Bv^1 + C = Au + Bv + C$$
$$y_3 = Au^2 + Bv^2 + C$$
$$y_4 = Au^3 + Bv^3 + C$$
$$y_5 = Au^4 + Bv^4 + C$$

I know $A, B, \alpha$ and $\beta$ have multiple solutions that satisfy the equation, but I do not care about their values. I just need an expression for $c$ in terms of $y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4$ and  $y_5$.

Trouble is, I haven't done much mathamatics for 20 years, and I'm getting into a terrible muddle trying to solve the 4th and 5th equations.

Any assistance would greatly appreciated.

I have solved the simpler version of the equation using this method, and it did indeed work.

$$y = Ae^{-\alpha t} + C$$

This of course only generated 3 simultaneous equations, and had no multiple roots, so was trivial to calculate.

Comment: Do you know that $\alpha \neq \beta$?

Comment: yep they are different, - or else it would be very easy!

Comment: Just curious about context, is this something that you are doing real time? Do you know the ranges of the parameters $\alpha,\beta$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be hard to solve by hand.  Here is the solution from Mathematica:

$$C = \frac{y_3^3-2 y_2 y_4 y_3-y_1 y_5 y_3+y_1 y_4^2+y_2^2 y_5}{y_2^2-2 y_3 y_2-2 y_4 y_2+2 y_5 y_2+3 y_3^2+y_4^2-y_1 y_3+2 y_1 y_4-2 y_3 y_4-y_1 y_5-y_3 y_5}. $$

Comment: Interestingly, the Mathematica solution fails if A=B=0, u=0, or v=0.  It worked correctly for several randomly chosen test cases.

Comment: Thanks - Never even thought of using software to solve it. What a dummy. I presume Octave could do the same - Did you use the "solve()" functions?

I can't try your solution right now - but thanks for the post.

Comment: I typed  "Solve[ {A + B + C == y[1], C + A u + B v == y[2],  C + A u^2 + B v^2 == y[3], C + A u^3 + B v^3 == y[4],  C + A u^4 + B v^4 == y[5]}, {A, B, C, u, v}]" into Mathematica.

Comment: You might be able to paste the following code into your favorite computer language "(Power(y(3),3) - 2*y(2)*y(3)*y(4) + y(1)*Power(y(4),2) + Power(y(2),2)*y(5) - y(1)*y(3)*y(5))/(Power(y(2),2) - y(1)*y(3) - 2*y(2)*y(3) + 3*Power(y(3),2) + 2*y(1)*y(4) - 2*y(2)*y(4) - 
     2*y(3)*y(4) + Power(y(4),2) - y(1)*y(5) + 2*y(2)*y(5) - y(3)*y(5))"